# Creation of a dictionary for m=5 floors and n =8 apartments

Tags: python, dictionary

Please assist how can I create a dictionary with 5 floors and 8 apartments on each floor. Want to be dynamic with floors and apartments meaning I can increase/decrease floors and apartments , so need your help.

I tried below

```
floors = [1,2,3,4,5] apts = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

dictionary = dict(zip(floors, apts)) 
print(dictionary)
```

Output

```
{1:1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}
```

Expected Output :

```
dictionary = {1:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],2:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],....5:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you are using incrementing numbers for the keys, I think it would be better to use a 2d list for this purpose.

Comment: do you have flors with different numbers of appartments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dict-comprehension would do it nicely

```
dictionary = {floor: list(apts) for floor in floors}
```

Comment: why `list(apts) ` rather than `apts` ? ;)

Comment: or `apts=6` and then `list(range(apts))`

Comment: @bruno to make copy of it, without, all values would point to the the SAME list, and modyfing one would be repercute on all others

Comment: @user_na I agree may be the OP wants a function getting the number of floors and of apartments rather than working on already built lists